# Restricting assert-soft to satisfiability only in optimization scenario possible?

Tags: optimization, z3, smt

When using mixed `assert` and `assert-soft` in optimization tasks, e.g. `maximize`, the soft assertions are disregarded, if they would lead to a non-optimal result.

Is it possible to restrict the "softness" to the satisfiability search only? I.e.: If the soft assertion is satisfiable *at all*, it is kept and then treated as "hard" assertion in the optimization?

Example exhibiting the aforementioned:

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)

(assert (< (+ x y) (* x y)))
(assert (>= x 0))
(assert (>= y x))
;(assert-soft (>= (* 4 x) y)); x->2, y->500
(assert (>= (* 4 x) y)); x->16, y->62
(assert (<= (* x y) 1000))

(maximize (+ x y))

(set-option :opt.priority pareto)
(check-sat)
(get-value (x y (+ x y) (* x y)))
(check-sat)
(get-value (x y (+ x y) (* x y)))
;...
```

This would be required to fulfill the following use case:

- Given a complex fixed ruleset on a large (>1000) number of variables (mostly having a finite domain), a user can choose the desired values for any of those, which may lead to conflicts with the ruleset.
- The individual values for a variable have ratings/weights.

So, given a set of user-selected (possibly conflicting) selections, the ruleset itself and finally the ratings of the set of all possible selections, *one* solution for all variables is to be found, which, while respecting all non-conflicting selections by the user, maximizes the total rating score.

I had the idea of using `assert-soft` for user selections to cancel out conflicting ones, while combining it with the optimization of z3 to get the "best" solution. However, this failed, which is the reason for this question.

Comment: Your question seems to be slightly ambiguous: what if your your group of soft-clauses admits multiple same-weight sub-sets of satisfiable soft-clauses that are mutually exclusive? Do you really want to keep the same sub-set of satisfiable soft-clauses as hard, or explore all of them?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: Actually, the problem I deal with lets the user make some (possibly unsatisfiable) choices (which would be modeled as soft assertions) in a model with complex rules. The optimization step shall find the best solution according to a target function, respecting the user's choices best it can, i.e.: As long as they are satisfiable, they are not to be discarded.

Comment: From the way in which you are formulating your problem I can't tell the priority order among optimizing the objective function and respecting the user's choices. Therefore, I would say that using the *Pareto optimization*, as in your example, is exactly what you want. This does not fix the group of *satisfiable clauses* but actually explores all of them.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: The results I am getting say different: Only one result returned all the time for the "hard" assertion case, a different, but also unchanging result for the "soft" assertion case. It looks as if I will have to use hard assertions and in a conflicted state present the user with the unsat core and have him fix the conflict.

Comment: When I make `(>= (* 4 x) y)` soft, I get `2` solutions instead of one. A solution in which the constraint (which is satisfiable) is satisfied, and one in which is falsified. Did you comment the line `(assert (>= (* 4 x) y));` when making `(>= (* 4 x) y)` soft?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: Sorry. I meant, that I am getting the one answer first, which _disregards_ the soft assertion. That issue I could overcome by naming the soft assertion and running check-sat a few times, but is bound to fail with multiple soft assertions due to the exponential growth of possible solutions.

Comment: Assume you have two soft-clauses in your problem, A and B, both with the same weight. A and B are both satisfiable wrt. the original problem, but they are mutually exclusive: if A is satisfied, then B is unsatisfiable and viceversa. The value of obj is N when A is satisfied, and M when B is satisfied, with N > M. What is the solution that you want to get? Are you happy with B,M or do you need A,N? if A, B both being false yield an obj value of K which is larger than M and N, do you want to get K or N/M?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: `(A,N)`; `K` only if `A` and `B` are both unsatisfiable, i.e. the supremum of the weighting function, with all _satisfiable_ soft-assertions having been fulfilled.

Comment: there was a [bug](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1491) in `z3`, related to your question, which has now been fixed; therefore the lexicographic optimization approach described in my answer should now be able to find `(A, N)`.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is *yes, if you do it incrementally*.

Assume that the set of soft-clauses has only a **unique** Boolean assignment which makes its associated MaxSMT problem optimal.

Then, it is easy to make satisfiable soft-clauses hard by fixing the value of the associated objective function. Although `z3` does not allow to put explicit constraints on the name of a soft clause group *(AFAIK)*, one can do it implicitly by using a `lexicographic` multi-objective combination rather than a `pareto` one.

Now, in your example we **can** safely switch from `pareto` to `lexicographic` search because there is **only one** extra objective function in addition to the one implicitly defined by `assert-soft`. Assuming the value of the `assert-soft` group being fixed, the whole problem degenerates to a **single-objective** formula which in turn has always at-most-one Pareto-optimal solution.

Of course, this is not possible if one plans to add more objectives to the formula. In this case, the only option is to solve the formula **incrementally**, as follows:

```
(set-option:produce-models true)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)

(declare-fun LABEL () Bool)
(assert (and 
    (or (not LABEL) (>= (* 4 x) y))
    (or LABEL (not (>= (* 4 x) y)))
)) ; ~= LABEL <-> (>= (* 4 x) y)
(assert-soft LABEL)

(assert (< (+ x y) (* x y)))
(assert (>= x 0))
(assert (>= y x))
(assert (>= (* 4 x) y))
(assert (<= (* x y) 1000))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
(push 1)
; assert LABEL or !LABEL depending on its value in the model

(maximize (+ x y))
; ... add other objective functions ...
(set-option :opt.priority pareto)
(check-sat)
(get-value (x y (+ x y) (* x y)))
(check-sat)
(get-value (x y (+ x y) (* x y)))
...
(pop 1)
```

This solves the MaxSMT problem first, fixes the Boolean assignment of the soft-clauses in a way that makes them hard, and then proceeds with optimizing multiple objectives with the `pareto` combination.

---

Note that, if the MaxSMT problem admits multiple same-weight solutions for the same optimal value, then the previous approach would discard them and focus on only one assignment. To circumvent this, the ideal solution would be to fix the value of the MaxSMT objective rather than fixing its associated Boolean assignment, **e.g.** as follows:

```
(set-option:produce-models true)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(declare-fun LABEL () Bool)

(assert-soft (>= (* 4 x) y) :id soft)    

(assert (< (+ x y) (* x y)))
(assert (>= x 0))
(assert (>= y x))

(assert (>= (* 4 x) y))
(assert (<= (* x y) 1000))

(minimize soft)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(push 1)
; assert `soft` equal to its value in model, e.g.:
; (assert (= soft XXX )))

(maximize (+ x y))
; ... add other objective functions ...
(set-option :opt.priority pareto)
(check-sat)
(get-value (x y (+ x y) (* x y)))
(check-sat)
(get-value (x y (+ x y) (* x y)))
...
(pop 1)
```

At the time being, this kind of syntax for objective combination is supported by `OptiMathSAT` only. Unfortunately, `OptiMathSAT` does not yet support *non-linear arithmetic* in conjunction with optimization, so it can't be reliably used on your example.

Luckily, one can still use this approach with `z3`!

If there is only one extra objective function in addition to the group of soft-clauses, one can still use the `lexicographic` combination rather than `pareto` one and get the same result.

Otherwise, if there are multiple objectives in addition to the group of soft-clauses, it suffices to **explicitly encode** the MaxSMT problem with a Pseudo-Boolean objective as opposed to using the `assert-soft` command. In this way, one retains full control of the associated objective function and can easily fix its value to any number. Note, however, that this might decrease the performance of the solver in dealing with the formula depending on the quality of the MaxSMT encoding.

Comment: Good ideas, alas somewhat involved (requiring interaction at runtime). I hoped that there might be an option to tell z3 to treat soft-assertions differently for satisfiability and optimization in the input model.

Comment: @Jinxed but in `z3` *soft-assertions* define an implicit MaxSMT objective on the optimization stack, so the solver is *"always running"* in optimization mode when these are defined.

Comment: I realized that, but that - of course - foils my intentions (see my comment to original question) somewhat. :(